# outside controller communication

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

How can a html element outside of a controller communicate with a given controller ?
The situation is as following:

<button name="search">Search</button> --> in an existing layout provided by an existing framework

<div ng-app ng-controller="overviewCtrl">

<div ng-view>/div> --> this one gets a specific controller

</div>

<button name="search">Search</button> --> in an existing layout provided by an existing framework

I don't have control on the location of the button outside of the controller. 
I can put attributes on it and I want to put an ng-click attribute.
It also fall outside the ng-app.

I could put a controller on it. But then I need a way to have a reference to the same controller.
What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use JQuery inside the Angular controller to bind the element outside the ng-app to a scope function through JQuery selector and click event.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have control over its position, but you do have control over its rendering in some way? You say you could put an ng-click on it?

I ask because there's an easy dodge here if that's true. You could make a simple directive that's basically a "smart ng-click". Your issue with ng-click is really that it's hard to route its call into your controller because the button is elsewhere. What you need, then, is just a way to bridge the two.

It would look something like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('SearchButtonClicked', function() {
      // I will be called whenever the search button is clicked...
      // and I am in my controller!
    });
  }])

  .directive('notifySearchClick', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function($scope, iElement) {
        iElement.bind('click', function() {
          $rootScope.$emit('SearchButtonClicked');
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Working Plunkr demonstrating this concept here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/dKuDl5?p=preview

The jQuery way is also perfectly valid but then you're back to the "what mystery event handlers are on THIS element" situation. It works, and it's reliable... but if you want to keep to the AngularJS philosophy, using a directive like the one above gives you a lot of flexibility.

Note that in the Plunkr reference above I added a tiny bit of sophistication. In that example I made the message name an attribute. You could thus use a single directive for any other cases like this in the future. Just put the message name into the attribute, like this:

```
<button notify-click="MyButtonNameClick"></button>
```

Comment: And it will also work also if the button is not within the ng-app element ?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. In an ideal world you would put your ng-app directive on the <html> or <body> tag. If you cannot do this then you're starting to quickly get out of the area AngularJS was designed to address, and falling back to a direct jQuery or similar binding is your best choice.